# How to play two videos side by side mode simultaneously in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, video-player

I need to play two videos simultaneously side by side for comparison. I am able to get the UI done. But only one video plays at one time. The other video plays only I pause the other video. I need two play both the videos simultaneously. Below is my current code :

```
SizedBox(
   width: deviceWidth,
   height: deviceHeight,
   child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
         SizedBox(
            width: deviceWidth / 2,
            child: _controller1 != null
            ? Chewie(
               controller: ChewieController(
               videoPlayerController: _controller1!,
               autoPlay: true,
               looping: true,
            ),
         )
         : const Center(
            child: Text(
               'No video selected',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
             ),
          ),
       ),
       SizedBox(
          width: deviceWidth / 2,
          child: _controller2 != null
              ? Chewie(
                 controller: ChewieController(
                 videoPlayerController: _controller2,
                 autoPlay: true,
                 looping: true,
               ),
            )
            : const Center(
               child: Text(
                  'No video selected',
                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
             ),
          ),
       ],
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This issue report](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/chewie/issues/536) suggests setting `mixWithOthers` to `true` on the `VideoPlayerController` that you pass to `ChewieController`.

```
videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(
  videoUrl,
  videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true),
);
```

Comment: I did try that, it doesn't work